# How can I resolve the Moodle 4.3 installation error related to the PHP configuration and dynamic extensions?

Tags: php, installation, moodle

After completing the installation on the web browser right before I can set up my Moodle, I receive this error message: Installation must be finished from the original IP address, sorry. and if I press continue I receive another error message: Cannot initialize PHP session. Please verify that your browser accepts cookies.

To resolve the first message, I tried to do the installation all on one aws server without stopping it so as to have the same Ip and to resolve the second one I allowed all cookies to work on my browser please help.

Comment: If this is an issue of installing Moodle, without having written any code on your own, this is off-topic here

Comment: Check these variables in `config.php` are pointing to the correct locations `$CFG->wwwroot`, `$CFG->dirroot`, `$CFG->dataroot`